# Continue subscribing for data even after error from Observable - rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm new to rx java and in the below code whenever there is a exception the subscriber stop's subscribing the data. In this case "hello3" is never printed.
How can I make the subscriber to continue receiving data?

```
public class ReactiveDataService
{
  public Observable<String> getStreamData()
  {
    return Observable.create(o -> {
        o.onNext("hello1");
        o.onNext("hello2");
        o.onError(new TimeoutException("Timed Out!"));
        o.onNext("hello3");
    });
  } 
}

Observable<String> watcher = new ReactiveResource().getData()
    .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .onErrorResumeNext(th -> {
        return Observable.just("timeout exception");
    });

    watcher.subscribe(
            ReactiveResource::callBack, 
            ReactiveResource::errorCallBack,
            ReactiveResource::completeCallBack
    );

public static Action1 callBack(String data)
{
    System.out.println("--" + data);
    return null;
}

public static void errorCallBack(Throwable throwable)
{
    System.out.println(throwable);      
}

public static void completeCallBack()
{
    System.out.println("On completed successfully");
}


private Observable<String> getData()
{
    return new ReactiveDataService().getStreamData();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJava only allows at most one `onError` which means the end of the flow. If you find yourself wanting to emit more errors, possibly interleaved with normal items, it means you need a data type, a pair or record class, that can represent both. The [`io.reactivex.Notification`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Notification.html) is one option.

```
public Observable<Notification<String>> getStreamData() {
    return Observable.create(o -> {
        o.onNext (Notification.createOnNext("hello1"));
        o.onNext (Notification.createOnNext("hello2"));
        o.onError(Notification.createOnError(new TimeoutException("Timed Out!")));
        o.onNext (Notification.createOnNext("hello3"));
        o.onComplete();
    });
}
```